# iText TextField.MULTIPLE cell height

Tags: java, itext

When i put a MULTIPLE ListField in a table cell, iText doesn't calculate cell height correctly, and the cell is smallert than the ListField.

In the demo code cell.setFixedHeight(70) solves this problem.
https://github.com/DonC83/Test/blob/master/IText/src/part2/chapter08/ChoiceFields.java

Any idea/hint how to fix this flaw in general?

Comment: In cellLayout() did you try to add the text to the cell instead of using the writer?

Comment: No. I don't know how to add a TextField to a cell. cell.addElement doesn't work since TextField isn't an Element. Please can you specify how to do this? For a quick hack i compute the cell height from the font properties and ltem number, it seems to work(mostly).

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the part about TextField problem.